# Form of the one-pion exchange potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, potential, strong-force, pions

Part of the one pion exchange potential (OPEP) contains the following term

$$V(r) \propto (\vec{\sigma}^{(1)} . \nabla)(\vec{\sigma}^{(2)} . \nabla) \frac{\exp\left(- \frac{r}{R}\right)}{r} $$

And I am trying to show that this can be re-written as

$$V(r) \propto \left[(\vec{\sigma}^{(1)} . \vec{r})(\vec{\sigma}^{(2)} . \vec{r})\left(\frac{1}{R^2r^3} + \frac{3}{Rr^4} + \frac{3}{r^5} \right) - \vec{\sigma}^{(1)}.\vec{\sigma}^{(2)} \left( \frac{1}{Rr^2} + \frac{1}{r^3} \right) \right] \exp \left(-\frac{r}{R} \right)$$

So that I can get the OPEP in terms of the tensor operator $S_{12}$. The information I am given is $\nabla f(r)=\vec{r}\frac{1}{r}\frac{df}{dr}$  and  $\nabla(\vec{a}.\vec{r})=\vec{a}$, however I have so far been unable to manipulate the $\nabla$'s and could do with some help. In particular I'm unsure as to where the $\vec{\sigma}^{(1)}.\vec{\sigma}^{(2)}$ term comes from Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don’t forget the *contact term* $\propto ({{s}_{1}}\cdot {{s}_{2}}){{\delta }^{3}}(\mathbf{x})$.   Since $V(r)$ is singular at the origin, you should replace *r* by $\sqrt{{{r}^{2}}+{{\varepsilon }^{2}}}$ and take the limit.

Answer (score 1):

The operators here are tricky.  Remember that the spin operator $\vec\sigma$ is a vector whose components are each matrices, so
\begin{align}
\vec\sigma \cdot \vec\nabla
&=
\sigma_x  \frac\partial{\partial x} +
\sigma_y  \frac\partial{\partial y} +
\sigma_z  \frac\partial{\partial z} 
\end{align}

is a $2\times2$ matrix of scalar operators.
You can interpret the hint you have this way:

$$
\vec\nabla f(r) = \frac{\vec r}r \frac{df}{dr}
\quad\implies\quad
\hat x\frac\partial{\partial x}f = \frac{\vec x}{r} \frac{df}{dr},
$$

and likewise for $y$ and $z$,
where $\hat x = \vec x / x$ is the unit vector in the $x$-direction
and $\vec r = \vec x + \vec y + \vec z$.

If you can't magically see how to make the connection by manipulating the $\vec\nabla$, go the long way around and manipulate the partial derivatives in each direction separately, then look for common terms you can collect to make your final expression.  The power of $R$ in the denominator tells you how many times you've differentiated the exponential to get to any particular term.